# How to use <head> tag with Angular directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20404559/2885923) in my Angular app, but it does not work. So I tried inserting a custom tag(`<mytag>`) into the head and made the directive work with this by replacing "head" with "mytag".

This however is not really what I intended, because it adds `<mytag>` to the body instead of the `<head>`

Does anyone know how to make it work with the head-tag?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same challenge. Make sure that your angular app is initialized on the html tag. Then this solution works out of the box.

However for us this was not an ideal solution. So I modified Zack Boman (tennisgent) https://github.com/tennisgent/angular-route-styles code, so that it could be used anywhere after app initialization.

- Renamed the directive to:  zbRouteStyles
- Modified the restrict to include attributes: restrict: 'EA'
- Changed the line: `elem.append($compile(html)(scope));`
  to
  `angular.element('head').append($compile(html)(scope));`

With these changes I was able to add the directive to any tag after my angular app was initialized even the tag that my app is initialized on.

e.g.:

`<div ng-app="myApp"  zb-Route-Styles>
<div>`

Comment: After your pull-request on Github was merged, this routeStyles worked out of the box. Thanks!