# I need to exclude a stylesheet from a particular route of an angular app

Tags: css, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have an angular app thats using materialize css (a css framework similar to bootstrap) all throughout the app. However there is one route where I want no css applied at all except for one custom stylesheet. All of my css link tags are in my index.html and all of my routes are being rendered inside of a ui-view, so they all get all of the included stylesheets applied to them because of this. How can I specify that on this particular route, I don't want this materialize css file loaded?

Comment: It's pretty involved, but [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20404559/548997) provides a very comprehensive solution.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to load the css files in each individual view instead of the index to accomplish this, or you would need to override the offending css.  Neither situation is ideal.  Not sure if you are using ui router but you may want to look at this post. [ui router css linking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25199047/best-way-to-include-specific-css-js-files-with-ui-router)