# How to include css or javascript files in partial view of angularjs application...?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I am new to angularjs, my application is having many partial views. I am not able to include css files javascript file in my partial view when i try to load partial view in main page.

I am not able to include css files for `dashview.html` any one help me sort out this problem.

```
routerApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');

    $stateProvider      
        .state('home', {
            url: '/home',
            templateUrl: 'dashview.html'
        })         
        .state('about', {
             url: '/about',
             templateUrl: 'taskpage.html',
             controller: 'customersController',
             /*controller: 'customersController1'*/ 
        })
        .state('user', {
             url: '/user',
             templateUrl: 'editors.html',
             controller: 'customersController1'
        })
        .state('adduser', {
            url: '/adduser',
            templateUrl: 'postuser1.html',
            controller:'UserController'
        });

});
```

Comment: here look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15193492/how-to-include-view-partial-specific-styling-in-angularjs) it might help you with adding css

Answer (score 0):

if you can copy the script and style codes directly inside partials without having them in separate .js and .css files and include them 
it may work

Comment: some how i managed to include css to my partial view.. but i am not able to include jquery inside my partial view...<script src="js/plugins/datepicker/bootstrap-datepicker.js" type="text/javascript"></script> i am using this file to include calendar in my partial view.. how can i do it...????