# AngularJS routing views properly but stylesheets broken

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I'm building an AngularJS application with routed views and to be clear the routing is working, as in the template pages in my /views/ folder are asynchronously loading into the view div on my index.html page.

The problem: These used to be seperate pages linked together the old fashioned way. Index.html, deal.html, and merchant.html. They all rendered perfectly in all browsers at that point but when I added this AngularJS routes feature, the same code is being dropped into the index.html file but the pages are not rendering properly. A lot of the styles are there... just misaligned. I can't wrap my head around it. I've looked everywhere and nobody seems to have documented this issue.

Here's what I've got so far:

head:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.25/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.25/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
```

The file system:

```
index.html 
app.js 
/views/main.html 
/views/merchant.html
/views/deal.html 
assets/css/ 
img/
```

index.html:

```
<div id="main">

     <div class="ng-view" autoscroll="true"></div>

</div>
```

My app.js:

```
var appName = angular.module('adamApp', ['ngRoute']);

// configure routes
appName.config(function($routeProvider) {
   $routeProvider.when('/', {
      templateUrl : 'partials/home.html',
      controller  : 'mainController'
   });
   $routeProvider.when('/merchant', {
      templateUrl : 'partials/merchant.html', 
      controller  : 'merchantController'
   });
   $routeProvider.when('/deal', {
      templateUrl : 'partials/deal.html', 
      controller  : 'dealController'
   });

   $routeProvider.otherwise({ redirectTo: "/" });

});
```

Screenshot of old version of site without Angular routes:

[image: Screenshot of old version of site without Angular routes:]

Screenshot of Angular routes version with broken stylesheet:

[image: Screenshot of Angular routes version with broken stylesheet:]

Any ideas on what's going on?

Comment: providing a plunker url with your code is always helpful if you want to get faster replies. http://plnkr.co/

Answer (score 0):

If your html is under "views" in the file system, why are you declaring the templateUrl property to be "partials/..." ?

Change

```
  $routeProvider.when('/deal', {
      templateUrl : 'partials/deal.html', 
      controller  : 'dealController'
   });
```

to

```
  $routeProvider.when('/deal', {
      templateUrl : 'views/deal.html', 
      controller  : 'dealController'
   });
```

and a piece of advice: drop ngRoute and use ui-router which is become the defacto standard for routing. https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router

Comment: Thanks for the tip about the ui-router. The views/partials error was just an error here on stackoverflow, it matches up in my code. sorry about that ;x

Comment: like i said in the post, the views are working properly just css isnt displaying correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this can help:

[How to include view/partial specific styling in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15193492/how-to-include-view-partial-specific-styling-in-angularjs)

and pay attention to the point

**2. Specify which stylesheets belong to which routes using the $routeProvider**

Comment: I saw this, it looked promising but complicated for my situation. I would have to go through thousands of lines of code and divide the code into chunks to create these partial.css files for each view. I may end up doing this for lack of a better option. thanks