# how to run javascript and css in a angular directive output?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I have a angular directive:

```
app.directive('templater', function() {
  return{
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: '../../tmpl/themer.html',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs){
       // execute metisMenu plugin
        setTimeout(function(){
            $(element).templater();
        }, 1);
    }
  }
});
```

The intent is to push the html from themer.html into a main page.

Right now inside my my_profile.html I have the tag `<templater></templater>`.

Now, the html displays perfectly, however the css and js are non-operational.  THe css tags in the template referenced by the directive affect and are affected by the same js and css files associated with the parent document.

How do I tell the directive to enforce the rules of the parent file on the inserted file?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You will not load `css` & `js` files from the partial view, as the `link` & `script` tag will not loaded. Partial will only load the html from it. If you want to make them working refer [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15193492/how-to-include-view-partial-specific-styling-in-angularjs)

**Side Note**

You should `$timeout` instead of `setTimeout`, that will ensure your angular element has updated with binding on html.

```
   // execute metisMenu plugin
    $timeout(function(){
        $(element).templater();
    }, 1);
```

Comment: thanks.  `link` and `script` are in the parent html document, not the embedded document.  I think I have my link wrong.  all I want to do is modularize my parent document with a bunch of embeds.  I was told to use directives as tmpl templates.  To that end, I moved my html into a template file and loaded it using a directive.  But now my css and js no longer work inside that template module.    What do I do?  Thanks.

Comment: @arcee123 refer this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15193492/how-to-include-view-partial-specific-styling-in-angularjs

Answer (score 0):

Use $timeout of angular instead of the setTimeOut.
Inject the $timeout dependency in directive

Comment: can you please give example?  I'm not educated on $timeout in this basic movement.  Thanks.