# Different style sheets for different parent pages

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am struggling with tweaking my Angular JS application.

There is the whole application where in the end I'd like to use my `app.css` file as a style sheet. So each state like:

- `domain/#/articles`
- `domain/#/articles/1`
- `domain/#/users`
- `domain/#/users/1`

will use this file.

However I do have a cms section in my application (i.e.  `domain/#/cms/articles` and I'd like to use completely different styles there (nothing in common with `app.css`). Is there anything I could do to easily load `cms.css` for selected states and do NOT load `app.css` there?

My initial idea was to add two style sheets in my `index.html` file with either `ng-if` or `ng-show` for each but that's definitely not a good approach (most likely it wouldn't even work).

Comment: use injecting CSS. and depending on page load css dynamically.. add caching for CSS. https://medium.com/opinionated-angularjs/angular-dynamically-injecting-css-file-using-route-resolve-and-promises-7bfcb8ccd05b#.fetyejbmn

Answer (score 0):

What about assigning a top-level class to each page, and then nesting the styles that are unique to that page within it? This is made even simpler if you're using a CSS preprocessor like LESS or SASS.

For example, you'd have something like this:

```
<div class='main-page' ng-controller='main'>
    <p>Some text</p>
    <p>Some more text</p>
</div>

<div class='cms-page' ng-controller='cms'>
    <p>Some CMS text</p>
    <p>Some more CMS text</p>
</div>
```

And then in your CSS:

```
.main-page {
//main styles here
    background-color: black;

    p {
        color: white;
    }
}

.cms-page {
//cms styles here
    background-color: red;

    p {
        color: blue;
    }
}
```

Extrapolate that idea as needed, but now you don't need to worry about reusing class names or having styles on one page conflict with styles on another, as everything is nested safely in its page class.

For global styles, of course, you just leave them out of the top-level page classes.

Comment: This approach would require to load all the styles at once if I am not mistaken. Also in my situation there are no "global" styles (at least there is nothing in common between both style sheets).

Comment: Ah, sorry. I didn't notice that you don't want to load all the styles. 

For route-based styles, you could take a look at what this guy has done: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15193492/how-to-include-view-partial-specific-styling-in-angularjs

He's using angular router, but I don't see any reason it wouldn't work for ui-router.

Comment: I've seen his idea and will try to make it a friend with a gulp inject :), not sure how it will work though.