# Is there a way to conditionally load style sheets based on the partial you have loaded? (angular ui router)

Tags: css, angularjs, d3.js, angular-ui-router, partials

I am using [angular ui router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) to do my routing for my application. I am essentially doing a collection of d3 visualizations, with each state/partial being it's own visualization.

Something like this

```
/#/line_graph?dataset=foo

/#/heat_map?dataset=foo&month=December
```

This worked fine when I just had to worry about the line graph.. "state" I guess we can call it.

Now, I am introducing a heatmap visualization into the mix. I found one that [I liked](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063318) and just copied the css directly from the example.

However, I now am finding that this css is conflicting with the styling for the line graph. I tried to put the link tag inside my partial, like so

index.html

```
<body ng-controller="ParentCtrl">
    <main class='container-fluid' ui-view></main>
</body>
```

heatmap.html (the partial)

```
<link href='/path/to/my/stylesheet' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

This did not work.

I then tried a more hackish take on this approach.

```
<div ng-if='loadHeatMapStylesheet'>
    <link href='/path/to/my/stylesheet' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</div>
```

And my controllers

```
visualizationControllers.controller('ParentCtrl', [
    '$scope',
    function($scope) {
        $scope.loadHeatMapStylesheet = false;
    }
]);

visualizationControllers.controller('HeatMapCtrl', [
    '$scope',
    function($scope) {
        $scope.loadHeatMapStylesheet = true;
    }
]);
```

This also did not work, I am still seeing the conflicting styles. Now, I know that I could just go in and change the css so that things aren't conflicting, but I am simply going to run into this problem again the next time I want to try to add a new visualization.

So, given that I don't know a ton about CSS, is there a way to do what I am asking?

Comment: I found this solution https://github.com/GabrielDelepine/angular-css-injector

Comment: glad to see I wasn't the only one with this problem. Thanks!

Comment: Have you looked at this question ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15193492/how-to-include-view-partial-specific-styling-in-angularjs

Comment: I have not, but I will now!