# Change stylesheet href on index.html based on url after minification

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, minify

I'm working on a webpage developed with AngularJS and SASS, and depending on the browser url needs to change the stylesheet file.

Simplifying, I have two URL pointing to the same instance of the web, and depending on the URL, I need to load different stylesheet

- url_a.com -> stylesA.css
- url_b.com -> stylesB.css

In order to detect the url, i'm using Angulars *$location* service.

Local development works fine, but the deployed app, does not change styles.

Index.html:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" ng-href="styles/{{mainStylesSheet}}">
```

AppController

```
$rootScope.mainStylesSheet = ($location.host == 'urlA') ? main-a.css : main-b.css;
```

Appreciate your help. Thanks

Comment: can't you just deploy separate copies of the app?

Comment: You want to achieve something like on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15193492/how-to-include-view-partial-specific-styling-in-angularjs ?

Comment: @DanielA.White one of the requirements is not to use two instances of the app... :(

Comment: @ice13 actually... what I need to load is the entire main.css, which contains different _@imports_, not partial styles depending on the url "path".

Comment: could you rewrite it on your webserver?

Comment: @DanielA.White what do you mean?

Comment: some web servers can rewrite the response based on certain conditions

Comment: Is the problem that production doesn't work or stylesheet changing is not working? can you post a screenshot of what link looks like in production?

Comment: @ShyamBabu the problem is that in production, the app only loads bootstrap css, not my custom stylesheets. And of course, no css change between URLs.

Comment: In production index.html  check if link tag is appearing with correct URL. If it is not appearing in production only,then there is high chance that some minification might be affecting the url.