# angular routeProvider for stylesheet

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

so I had my style in my `main.css` declared in my `index.html`. But when I moved it to a separate file and tried to declare the style sheet within my routeProvider it is just showing a white page with my nav bar at the top (which is styled in the `main.css`).. My routeProvider provider looks like.

```
.when('/', {
    templateUrl: 'static/partials/landing.html',
    controller: IndexController
    css: 'static/css/home.css'
})
.when('/about', {
    templateUrl: 'static/partials/about.html',
    controller: AboutController
})
.when('/post', {
    templateUrl: 'static/partials/post-list.html',
    controller: PostListController
})
.when('/post/:postId', {
    templateUrl: '/static/partials/post-detail.html',
    controller: PostDetailController
})
/* Create a "/blog" route that takes the user to the same place as "/post" */
.when('/blog', {
    templateUrl: 'static/partials/post-list.html',
    controller: PostListController
})
.otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/'
});
```

This is my first time really playing with angular so I thought I might be missing something simple. I searched the web for a while a did not come up with much.

Comment: Have you checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15193492/how-to-include-view-partial-specific-styling-in-angularjs) question right here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot just include css in the routerProvider without a library or a directive to compile, alternatively you can use **[`angular-css`](https://github.com/castillo-io/angular-css)**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute', 'angularCSS']);
```

and then provide the individual css in the configuration.

Comment: This helped. Thanks for the link.